# Bsod, irq_not_equal, can boot into safe mode

Tags: windows-7, irq

Windows 7 64 bit crashes to bsod, irq_not_equal. I can boot into safe mode but cannot uninstall programs.

Error from repair computer on windows installation disc:

```
Root cause found:

Unspecified changes to system configuration might have caused a problem.

Repair action: System files integrity check and repair
Result: Failed. Error code = 0x490
Time taken = 1170757 ms
```

[Minidump folder](https://www.dropbox.com/s/99195jbvbsin9oo/Minidump.zip)

Comment: We need to know specific driver information.   Try booting into a minimal normal bootup

Comment: @Ramhound how would i do that? Also, i Rand repair conputer fron the Windows installation disc, one of the tests had an error in it, ill put it in the op

Comment: The process of selecting which drivers are loaded is well documented.

Comment: @Ramhound of right in the bootuo, i was confused. Ill find that and then add it to OP, but maybe tomorrow because its 11:00pm where i live :)

Comment: That test took almost 20 minutes that indicates a major mechanical problem.

Comment: @Ramhound im using a laptop, probably not fixable myself. *Sigh* Not looking forward to dealing with Toshiba custoner support

Comment: You can't fix this problem with either a recovery disk or the installation media.

Comment: @Ramhound I have the installation disc. So reinstalling Windows would fix this problem?

Comment: It might.  If the HDD has mechanical problems it won't.

Comment: @Ramhound i did have some problems booting from the hard drive a while ago. I dont quite remember what was wrong, but up until now it seems to be working mostly fine. Thanks for the advice, i will try reinstalling

Comment: copy the folder **C:\Windows\Minidump** to an external drive, zip it, and upload the zip from a second PC (OneDrive, Dropbox) nad post a link here.

Comment: @magicandre1981 added to the OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the dump, the crash can be caused by a Norton/Symantec tool (SYMNETS.sys)

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL (a)
An attempt was made to access a pageable (or completely invalid) address at an
interrupt request level (IRQL) that is too high.  This is usually
caused by drivers using improper addresses.
If a kernel debugger is available get the stack backtrace.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000, memory referenced
Arg2: 0000000000000002, IRQL
Arg3: 0000000000000001, bitfield :
    bit 0 : value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation
    bit 3 : value 0 = not an execute operation, 1 = execute operation (only on chips which support this level of status)
Arg4: fffff80003a93c3f, address which referenced memory

Debugging Details:
------------------


OVERLAPPED_MODULE: Address regions for 'pgeffect' and 'RtsUStor.sys' overlap

WRITE_ADDRESS: GetPointerFromAddress: unable to read from fffff80003cc2100
GetUlongFromAddress: unable to read from fffff80003cc21c0
 0000000000000000 Nonpaged pool

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

FAULTING_IP: 
nt!KeAcquireInStackQueuedSpinLockAtDpcLevel+4f
fffff800`03a93c3f 488713          xchg    rdx,qword ptr [rbx]

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0xA

PROCESS_NAME:  System

STACK_TEXT:  
nt!KeBugCheckEx
nt!KiBugCheckDispatch
nt!KiPageFault
nt!KeAcquireInStackQueuedSpinLockAtDpcLevel
NETIO!WfpExpireEntryLru
tcpip!WfpAleCloseRemoteEndpointConnection
tcpip! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
tcpip!WfpAleHandleSendCompletion
tcpip!WfpAlepAuthorizeSendCompletion
tcpip!WfpAleCompleteOperation
fwpkclnt!FwpsCompleteOperation0
SYMNETS


FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0xA_NETIO!WfpExpireEntryLru+17

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:x64_0xa_netio!wfpexpireentrylru+17


    Loaded symbol image file: SYMNETS.SYS
    Image path: \SystemRoot\System32\Drivers\N360x64\1501000.012\SYMNETS.SYS
    Image name: SYMNETS.SYS
    Timestamp:        Tue Sep 24 04:41:10 2013
```

Use [SafeMSI](http://windowsitpro.com/windows/jsi-tip-9233-safemsiexe-freeware-starts-windows-installer-safe-mode) to enable Windows Installer in safe mode and remove the tool.

Comment: @mm865 if it fixed it, mark my reply as answer.

Comment: Sorry, i thought i did!